# Convert microsoft access form into a html?

Tags: javascript, html, ms-access

I have a microsoft access form which I have to recreate using html.I'm new to access database and I have a access form UI which I need to redesign.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you build a form in vb.net, then such a form would have to be re-created from scratch by manually hand into HTML. They are completely different technologies.

If you build a form in FoxPro, then such a form would have to be re-created from scratch by manually hand into HTML. They are completely different technologies.

If you build a form in VB6, then such a form would have to be re-created from scratch by manually hand into HTML. They are completely different technologies.

If you build a form in c#, then such a form would have to be re-created from scratch by manually hand into HTML. They are completely different technologies.

Guess what?

If you build a form in Access, then such a form would have to be re-created from scratch by manually hand into HTML. They are completely different technologies.

If you build a form in [insert whatever non web based systems here], then a form would have to be re-created from scratch by manually hand into HTML. They are completely different technologies.

You can now build web forms using Access as I show in this video:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AU4mH0jPntI

However the forms in the above are created as Access “web” forms and there is no conversion of existing Access “desktop” forms to HTML or into Access web based forms. Such a process is manual process involving human labor and time.

If you buy a car, it cannot fly. So if you need to fly, then you need a different technology then a car.

If you need web based forms, then you have to use a tool designed for making web based forms and not a tool that creates desktop forms.

So Access can now create web based applications, and Access can now create web forms, existing desktop Access forms will have to be re-created.